# How to change labelCount on tablet? (when more space is available)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

We are developing an iOS app using Swift. 
We have a tableView where each TableCell is expandable.

It currently looks like this. (Ignore the abbreviation of the time label, this is not intended)
[image]

When executed on a tablet the labels from the expanded sub cell should be moved to the parent cell, depending on how much space is available. 
It would not be a problem if we have to make a separate scene for tablets and phones.

It would be beautiful, if we could change the display of those scenes directly in the interface builder, depending on which device is selected on the bottom bar.

What is the best (cleanest) way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need sounds like the "vary for traits" option in Xcode 8, it allows you to have different configurations of the same view depending on the device(actually based on Width and Height settings) but it narrow down to device as you use it, if you click the vary for traits button in Xcode you will see the various options for W and H and you can see in real time how the devices changes depending on your selection. Just be a little bit careful about one thing, when you introduce a new setting you use the vary for traits button but after that you access it from the right hand side picker as normal.

You will see in Xcode 8 that some attributes have a small + sign next to them, that is where you will find your different traits after you have introduced them, it takes some getting used to but is very powerful once you get your head around it. It is also the recommended way to make adaptive applications in iOS

Comment: So have I understood that right? I now would build a more extensive layout on tablet, after that click vary for traits and set the width and height of the additional labels to 0 for smaller devices?